# Changing the price of items in stripe in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I feel rather at a loss, I'm trying to create a simple storefront using stripe checkout in a rails app. I've been following the stripe tutorial, and got it working, but they hard code the price in the controller.

```
def create

    #amounts are in American cents

    @amount= 500
    #making a customer
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source => params[:stripeToken]
    )
    #a customer has an email and a token, provided by stripe

    #making a charge

    charge= Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe Customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
    )
    # a charge has a customer, found by customer id, an amount, a description, and a currency
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

and the view, which will be repeated for multiple products each costing different amounts

```
  <%= form_tag charges_path do %>
    <article>
      <% if flash[:error].present? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <label class="amount">
        <span>ITEM 1</span>
        <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
      </label>
    </article>

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
            data-description="A month's subscription"
            data-amount="500"
            data-billingAddress="true"
            data-shippingAddress="true"
            data-locale="auto"></script>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Of course everything is 5.00. I feel like this is a simple problem but I just can't solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a database table with your products, each with a description and a price. Add a model for the table, use the model in your controller and your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Stripe is only showing you an example. You need to add the price you want - for example with passing a global value from your controller.

```
...
<span>Amount: <%= @price %></span>
...
data-amount="<%= @price %>"
```

---

The question is: **where does the price come from?**

In a regular webshop you would have a `Product` model with a data-column: `price`.

Then you would call it (based on a normal REST-ROUTE Rails app) in the show action in the charges controller (i could imagine it was called something like that):

```
#controller
def show
  @price = Product.find(params[:id]).price
end
```

I hope it guides you in the right direction.

Comment: Man, I knew I was over-thinking it. Thanks for putting me on the right path

Comment: No problem. If it was the answer you were seeking, can you then accept it?